# How to filter out some values of grafana dashboard variable?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I have such a variable but it returns some values which I don't want to see(`template0` and `template1`)

[image]

How can I filter them out ?

I tried to write `label_values(datname!~"template.*|postgres")`

But grafana says that this definition has broken syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works(filter both: postgres and tempate database):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

try to improve the query as follows

```
label_values({datname=~".+", datname!~"template.*|postgres"}, datname)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: unofrtunately it filters all values except ALL

Comment: can you please provide the metric which we are filtering ?

Comment: It is cross metric value

` label_values(label) Returns a list of label values for the label in every metric. `

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/#query-variable

Comment: Okay now i understand. Try this: 
label_values({datname=~".+", datname!~"template.*|postgres"}, datname)
also edited my answer